# C# - YAXLib: How to ignore properties

Tags: c#, xml, yaxlib

I have to create XML document in the following format using  YAXLib library

```
 <Orders>
    <Order>
    <ItemNumber>
    <QTY>10</QTY>
    </ItemNumber>
    <WareHouse>PA019</WareHouse>
    </Order>
    </Orders>
```

I have the following class structure

```
public class Orders
    {
        private List<Order> _orders = new List<Order>();

        public List<Order> OrderList
        {
            get { return _orders; }
        }
    }

    public class Order
    {

        [YAXElementFor("")]
        [YAXSerializeAs("ItemNumber")]
        public string ItemNumber { get; set; }

        [YAXElementFor("ItemNumber")]
        [YAXSerializeAs("QTY")]
        public int QTY { get; set; }

        [YAXElementFor("")]
        [YAXSerializeAs("WareHouse")]
        public string WareHouse { get; set; }
    }
```

but whenever I use the above class structure , OrderList tag also appear as well

Any idea on ignoring the tags in C# - YAXLib, **what attribute need to add ?, [YAXIgnore] not found**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [YAXDontSerialize] attribute.